# What is the grammatical mistake here?

Tags: grammaticality

The sentences in question:

> From what I’ve heard from his classmates, he has a knack for explaining the tricky, intricate programming concepts in a very easy-to-understand manner. This skill of his clearly reveals that **his own** fundamental computer concepts are strong and crystal clear.

There is a green highlight on that bold part, and MS word says "Reflexive Pronoun Use (Consider revising)". However, I don't understand what's wrong at all. Please explain to me what is the mistake here. Thanks you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong. A reflexive pronoun would be impossible here.

Comment: @BillJ Please tell Mr. Nadella the same thing, as of now he isn't listening to my repeated attempts of "Ignore Once" :D

Comment: I ran the sentence through Word Spelling & Grammar checker on my PC and it found nothing wrong. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @BillJ It is indeed strange. Please see this https://pasteboard.co/GUvzHaR.png Note the green underline, and the first gray heading on the context menu.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I think that by "reflexive" your teacher meant to say that "own" was unnecessary, and I agree with him. We use "own" for emphasis, and there's no need for emphasis here.

Comment: @Gustavson I do feel there's a need of emphasis here. As you can see, I began the paragraph stating how he is able to clearly explain the concepts in an easy-to-understand manner to everyone else, which is only possible if his *own* concepts are clear. At least, that's how the general public would speak here in my locality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Word is really bad at grammar. The green squiggly is useful only for catching careless mistakes.

You ask what the mistake is in your sentence: there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer so I can finally close this question ^_^